# Appending docker stats per day to a single file

Tags: shell, docker

I am trying to log the docker stats every minute to a csv file in S3 bucket. The below command is run on putty.

```
while true; do docker stats --no-stream | aws s3 cp - s3://username/dockerstats/`date -u +"%Y%m%dT%H%M%S.csv"`; sleep 60; done
```

As it can be seen above, it is creating a new file every minute. I would like to append the docker stats to the same csv file. Can anyone let me know what would be the command to append data to the same file csv file? It would be one csv file per day.

Answer (score 7):

You redirect the output with `>>` to append to your file.

```bash
docker stats --no-stream >> "$(date -u +"%Y%m%d.csv")"
```

It will create the file if it doesn't exist, so it will work with your dynamic date file names.

If you only use one `>` it will not append to the file but completely overwrite it.

Comment: For windows users:
docker stats --no-stream >> "%Date:~6,4%_%Date:~3,2%_%Date:~0,2%.csv"